# Excel error - object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel

This line of code:

```
    Y.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = Y.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).value & " (" & Right(UserAndEid, Len(UserAndEid) - InStr(1, UserAndEid, "Emp") - 7) & ")"
```

Throws this error:

> Excel (2007) VBA Object doesn't support this property or method

`Y` is a declared workbook variable. `Sheets(1)` is the sheet I am addressing (not using the sheet caption name as it is changed by the same procedure).
`UserAndEid` is a piece of text taken from a cell in another declared workbook.

All I am doing is adding the peice of text to that which is already in the cell in row "A". I had it working yesterday, am sure I haven't changed anything, but today it will not work.

Any ideas?

Edit 
UserAndEid is declared as a string but will contain numbers.

```
 Dim UserAndEid As String
```

The whole line is highlighted in yellow in the debugger.

Comment: Are you sure `UserAndEid` is a string and not a number?

Comment: What is the IDE highlighting on when it throws the error?

Comment: See edits at end of question

Comment: `Y` is definitely declared as the workbook variable? Can you test that?

Comment: In Immediate window, run this: `?Y.Sheets(1).Name`, or add a line to your code above the error line: `Debug.Print Y.Sheets(1).Name`. Did you receive an error? Or did you receive the correct sheet name? If error, you can be sure the `Y` is the problem. Else, dont know.

Comment: Check Tools > References for any references marked as "Missing:" Any missing references can cause weird errors with built-in functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for the pointers,they helped me find the issue:

```
 Sheets(1)
```

I remembered that I had added a chart to the workbook and this was `Chart1`.
As `Sheets` includes Charts and Worksheets the addition of `Chart1` made `Sheets(1)` ambiguous, as it could no longer only be referring to 'Worksheets1'.

I have to say that the error message could have helped more here - if a variable is ambiguous the error message will say so, why not in the case of objects?

Comment: use `worksheets(1)` instead. the worksheets object does not include chart sheets